# Inserting a picture in a title page

Tags: titles, texmaker

I am trying to insert a picture in the first page of my report but it is becoming on a separate page or else it comes above the title. I want it to be between author and date:

```
\begin{document}


\title{bb}
\author{bb}
\date {bb}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3in]{figure1}
\end{figure}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I tried doing as shown below but I got an error with \titlehead:

```
\titlehead{\centering\includegraphics[width=3in]{figure1}}
```

Comment: Use `\author{bb\\[5mm] \includegraphics[width=3in]{figure1}}`

Comment: thanks so much! Can you use that for other figures in the document then and do \caption to give them a caption please?

Comment: Can you tell us which document class you are using? A better and more robust solution might be out there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no requirement that `\includegraphics` is in a `figure` environment, which is for including floating objects (including pictures) with their caption.

For your problem, use the `titling` package that allows customizing the `\maketitle` command adding items where needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

% set up \maketitle to accept a new item
\predate{\begin{center}\placetitlepicture\large}
\postdate{\par\end{center}}

% commands for including the picture
\newcommand{\titlepicture}[2][]{%
  \renewcommand\placetitlepicture{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par\medskip
  }%
}
\newcommand{\placetitlepicture}{} % initialization

\begin{document}

\title{A very important paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{38 July 2014}
\titlepicture[width=3in]{example-image}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

So long as you have `\titlepicture` before `\maketitle` you'll get the picture where you want it. Not specifying `\titlepicture` will do nothing different from the usual `\maketitle`.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's most easy with the `titling` package and its `maketitlehookx`commands that allow for inserting supplementary material for the `\maketitle` command. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{garamondx}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{About Piero di Cosimo}
\author{The author}

\setlength\droptitle {-38.5mm}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\itshape\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}\vskip2cm}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\postauthor{\end{center}\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{%
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}\par\vskip 3cm}%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

![image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add it directly to the `\author`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{A very important paper}
\author{A. Uthor\\[2ex]
        \includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image}\\[1ex]
        \small This is my title picture
        }
\date{38 July 2014}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @karlkoeller See ya Karl. Bye :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put an image inside your title. Simple :)

You can add a \texttt for formatting the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{./images/ }

\title{
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.png} Here is my Title
}
\author{Saurabh Adhikary}
.
.
.
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```