# Recreating this starting page in a book environment

Tags: thesis

I am starting to write my thesis, and I am trying to reproduce this starting page in the book document. However I am struggling on putting the image is the same part of the page. Any ideas?
Should I use the memoir document instead? 
[image]

This is what I tried so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\titlehead{\centering\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}}

\title{Thesis title}

\author{Name}

\date{July 2019}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\clearpage

\chapter*{Abstract}

My abstract 

\end{document}
```

However I get an error with `\titlehead` saying it is undefined.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that! I will edit in a minute.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214255/inserting-a-picture-in-a-title-page

Comment: `\titlehead` is from the `scrbook` class.  Note, usually you only load the `graphicx` package or the `graphics` package, not both; `graphicx` is the enhanced version.

Answer (score 1):

The layout from `\maketitle` is pretty much fixed. For anything else you usually have to specify your own layout. The `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`) **Chapter 4 Titles** describes some tools to help in this. **Chapter 21 An example thesis design** shows the code for a particular Thesis Title and Approval pages. However, something along the following lines (less any typos) and adding in appropriate vertical spaces should help.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%% The Title page
% vertical space
\begin{center}
Something crossed out
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Crossed out graphic % \includegraphics...
\end{center}
% vertical space
\begin{center}
\textsc{Master of ...} \\[2\baselineskip]
\textsc{\LARGE Master Degree Thesis}
\end{center}
% vertical space
\begin{center}
More stuff
\end{center}
% vertical space
\noindent Supervisor: \hfill Candidate: \\
Name \hfill Name
% vertical space

{\centering Date \par}
\clearpage
% and following pages
\end{document}
```