# Include graphic in title page

Tags: titles

I have been trying to figure out how to include a picture in my title page. I have used multiple suggestions found in forums but somehow none of them seems to work. 
The picture is either included on a separate page or is not included at all.
I would like the picture to be included underneath the date (please see the code below).

Hopefully, someone of you will be able to help me.

Thanks a lot already in advance.

So this is my Latex code:

```
\title{Bildungshub}

\author{Langhoff Charly (1172857) 

\and Pokrivka Helena (01460370)}

\date{Klagenfurt, am \today{}}

%%%%Here is where I would like my picture to be inserted

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagenumbering{roman} %% small roman page numbers

 \maketitle
```

Comment: Can you please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`? The document doesn't have to be long (the stuff you've already provided suffices) but the used `\documentclass` would be very interesting, as some might provide such option while others don't.

Comment: As @Skillmon said, document class is important here.  For example, in `memoir` you can use the `titlingpage` environment (i.e. `\begin{titlingpage}...\end{titlingpage}`).  Within it, you can put all the information you like, including images.

Comment: Does https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation help you?

Comment: As mentioned below by @Johannes_B, there are very similar questions which already have an answer, e.g. [question214255](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214255/inserting-a-picture-in-a-title-page) or [question287523](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287523/how-to-put-an-image-on-maketitle-page-below-the-authors-name).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code, with the `titling` package, which makes customising the `maketitle` command easy:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\droptitle{-3cm}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
\title{Bildungshub}
\posttitle{\end{center}\vskip 8ex}
 \preauthor{\begin{center}
\large%
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}}
\author{Langhoff Charly (1172857)\\[1ex]
 Pokrivka Helena (01460370)}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\end{center}\vskip3ex}
\date{Klagenfurt, am \today{}}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{\centering\vfill\includegraphics{pepe-le-pew2}\vfill}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haven't you answered the same question a few times by now? Why not mark as duplicate?

Comment: @Johannes_B : Just because I don't know exactly what I have answered – I am aware I have answered more or less similar questions, but I don't remember when anyway, so it's almost impossible to find them. Do you know such an answer of mine?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214255/inserting-a-picture-in-a-title-page or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287523/how-to-put-an-image-on-maketitle-page-below-the-authors-name